# How can I detect mouse position outside JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, mousemotionlistener

I have a `JTable` with some columns and rows. My idea was to detect mouse movement inside table and highlight rows that the mouse is pointing at. Though I want any highlight to disappear when the mouse is outside table which does not happen. I have some code in "if" statement but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

```
table.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        if (e.getPoint().x == 0 || e.getPoint().y == 0) {
            table.clearSelection();
        }
        table.changeSelection(table.rowAtPoint(p), table.columnAtPoint(p), false, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at `MouseListener`, it already provides methods to handle those events.

Comment: Deselect on `mouseExited`